# How can I make list scroll smoothly and avoid trigger itemtap when scroll List on Windows Phone

Tags: list, windows-phone-8, scroll, sencha-touch-2

I create a app use Sencha Touch2.3, some times on Windows Phone (Nokia Lumia 520, IE mobile 10 ) the list(Ext.dataview.List) scroll not smoothly.
And, many times I will scroll the list but itemtap event be trigger, so the callbak for itemtap be call.

How can I make the list smoothly?
How can I avoid tigger itemtap event when scroll the list?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be inserting a little more space between the items in itemtemplate of list. Try using MouseLeftButtonDown event instead of Tap.

Comment: goog, In Sencha Touch it's maybe onItemDisclosure: true config. And listen disclose event.